# Fail to import Parrot Security OVA for VMWare 15.5

Tags: vmware

I tried to import Parrot Security OVA into VMWare 15.5 and it is giving me the following errors:

Line 150: Unsupported element 'StorageItem'.

Line 159: Unsupported element 'EthernetPortItem'.

According to previous questions about Parrot Security OVA, it seems that VMWare requires another format to import. If so, can anyone please tell me a possible way to change the Parrot OVA format/ VMWare settings appropriately to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

OVA file is not recommended. ISO is best everytime. Since OVA is pre-configured it's easy to use but you may lack some requirements which will make it fail to import. On the other hand in ISO you can configure all , so chances of errors are less